# How to pass parameter to SelectMethod of gridView in asp .net 4.5

Tags: parameters, asp.net-4.5

Problem : How to pass parameter to SelectMethod  of gridView in asp .net 4.5

Description :

I am using asp .net 4.5 and using (strongly typed model binding) SelectMethod to bind data to gridView.

**SelecteMethod="BindGrid"**   BindGrid is user defined function.

But **while binding I want to pass GridRow as parameter to the function BindGrid.**

So is there any way to pass the parameters to selectMethod for strongly typed model binding ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [great example](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/03/SelectMethod-in-asp-net-45-Model-binding.html) of how you can use a control to "filter" the data returned from the "SelectMethod".  For example, if you are changing the data on a selection in a dropdown.  You would set up the markup like so...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEmployee" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetEmployees" ItemType="WebApplication2.Employee">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then the method would look something like this receiving a parameter...

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees([Control]int? ddlEmployee)
    {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            employeeList.Add(new Employee { 
                EmployeeId=i,
                FirstName=string.Format("First{0}",i),
                LastName=string.Format("Last{0}",i)
            });
        }
        return employeeList.Where(e=>e.EmployeeId==ddlEmployee).ToList();
    }
```

There are variations of this that can work depending on your situation.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two ways to pass parameters:

- Declaratively from the `SelectParameters` element.
- Programmatically from the `Selecting` method.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectmethod?view=netframework-4.8#parameter-merging).

I think in your case you'd have to chose the `Selecting` method.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN > Task 3 - Value Providers in Model Binding > (5): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/hands-on-labs/whats-new-in-web-forms-in-aspnet-45#task-3---value-providers-in-model-binding

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories([Control("controlId")] int? minProductsCount)
{
    var query = this.db.Categories.Include(c => c.Products);

    if (minProductsCount.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.Products.Count >= minProductsCount);
    }

    return query;
}
```